# How to convert .xlsm (macro enabled excel file) to .xlsx using Python?

Tags: excel, windows, python-2.7, xlsx, xlsm

I am trying to import data in an .xlsm file as a data frame. When I import the .xlsm file using the command below, it gives me an empty data frames as the result:

```
exp = pd.read_excel(File_Path+'file_name'.xlsx',sheetname='Data',header=None)
```

I have manually saved .xlsm files as .xlsx file and imported them as data frame.

Can anybody tell me how to save as .xlsm file as .xlsx using Python?

Comment: You need to post more code, or explain what libraries you are using.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest you try using a `win32com` type approach. If you are on Windows, you can use Python to automate Excel itself to carry out the conversion from an `.xlxm` file to `.xlsx` format. The file can then be read correctly using the usual Pandas `pd.read_excel()` function.

This can be done as follows:

```
import win32com.client as win32

excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')

# Load the .XLSM file into Excel
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(r'input.xlsm')

# Save it in .XLSX format to a different filename
excel.DisplayAlerts = False
wb.DoNotPromptForConvert = True
wb.CheckCompatibility = False
wb.SaveAs(r"output.xlsx", FileFormat=51, ConflictResolution=2)
excel.Application.Quit()

# Load the .XLSX file into Pandas
df = pd.read_excel('output.xlsx', sheetname='Data', header=None)
```

I suggest you add full paths to the filenames.